# How can I make PHP output from SQL have unique names for each element I can access with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to make simple cms; the code below is index.php.

Now I can't find the way to make jquery select each item, because they have the same name.
For example i want to do is: select (on $(.subject)).hover then (a $(.subjectpic)).show

How to make them have their own names?

```
<?php
if(!$query){
    print "submit error";
}
else {
    while($list=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        print"
        <div class=\"subjectwrap\">
                <div class=\"subject\">$list[subject]</div>
                <div class=\"subjectpic\">$list[subjectpic]</div>
        </div>
        ";
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: It's more a `jQuery` question. You can use jquery's `.each()` to have a function which will take effect on every class.

Comment: @Alexlunix Found it: `How to make they have own name or any suggestion??`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options. You can either do it all with jQuery, selecting the sibling subjectpic:

```
$('.subject').hover( function() {
   $(this).closest('.subjectwrap').find('.subjectpic').show();
});
```

Or you can do it with PHP, assigning each a numerical data-subject index:

```
<?php
if(!$query){
    print "submit error";
}
else {
    $i = 1;
    while($list=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        print"
        <div class=\"subjectwrap\">
                <div class=\"subject\" data-subject=\"$i\">$list[subject]</div>
                <div class=\"subjectpic\" data-subject=\"$i\">$list[subjectpic]</div>
        </div>
        ";
        $i++;
    }
}   
?>
```

By assigning a numerical index in PHP, you could then target it with jQuery:

```
$('.subject').hover( function() {
    var thisSubject = $(this).attr('data-subject');
    $('.subjectpic[data-subject=' + thisSubject + ']').show();
});
```